# Explain the error "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:....../chat' failed:"

Tags: reactjs, .net, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

`enter code here`Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.[Image of the error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmbXn.png)

I am new to React and .net with signalR and I tried many answers from stackoverflow and other sources but the error still exists and I think I have not correctly configured the server. But I have no idea how to do it in .net 6. explain me about how to configure the signalR server with the React frontend in .net 6

```
//Program.cs
using ChatSignalR;
using ChatSignalR.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3002")
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials();

    });

});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDictionary<string, 
UserConnection>> 
   (opts => new Dictionary<string, UserConnection>());

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
});
app.Run();
```

This is the Hub I created

```
//ChatHub.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace ChatSignalR.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly string _chatBot;

        public ChatHub()
        {
            _chatBot = "MyChat Bot";
        }

        public async Task JoinRoom(UserConnection userConnection)
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(userConnection.User, userConnection.Room);
            await Clients.Group(userConnection.Room).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", _chatBot,
                $"{userConnection.User} has joined {userConnection.Room}");
        }
    }
}

//UserConnection.cs
namespace ChatSignalR
{
    public class UserConnection
    {
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Room { get; set; }
    }
}
```

these are the launch settings

```
//launchSettings.json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3456",
      "sslPort": 44385
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "ChatSignalR": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7261 ;http://localhost:5080",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
         "WDS_SOCKET_PORT": "0" 
      }
    },
```

Front end is in react and i am halfway through the code due to this error

```
//front end App.js
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Lobby from './Components/Lobby';
import {HubConnectionBuilder,LogLevel,HttpTransportType} from '@microsoft/signalr'
import { useState } from 'react';
function App() {
  const [connection,SetConnection] = useState();
  const joinroom = async (user,room) => {
    try{
      const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:44385/chat", {
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
      .build();

      connection.on("ReceiveMessage",(user,message)=>{
        console.log('message received: ', message);
      });

      await connection.start();
      await connection.invoke("JoinRoom",{user,room});
      SetConnection(connection);
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Mychat</h2>
      <hr className='line'/>
      <Lobby joinroom={joinroom} />

      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Pls share the doc you refered, and you also need to share the Hub class and Program.cs file. And the frontend init Hub method also required.

Comment: I added the required parts and hope this is enough thank you in advance

Comment: Change `http://localhost:44385/chat` to `https://localhost:44385/chat`. I am waiting for your update.  You can find here: const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:44385/chat", {
        skipNegotiation: true,

Comment: Still it gives the same error nothing has changed

Comment: Could you share me the sample project, pls hide the sensitive information. So that I could help you check the issue.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am waiting for your updates.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the init method in frontend.

Use

```
https://localhost:44385/chat
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:44385/chat
```

---

**Complete code like below:**

```
const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("http://localhost:44385/chat", {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
   })
  .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
  .build();
```